# How to consume a Rest web service in java6?

Tags: java, rest, java-ee-6

I want to consume this URL: `https://197.5.145.85:13002/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=bar&password=bar&from=&to=21652031757`

```
public void postFromURL(String url) { 
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer ");
    ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url,null, Object.class);    
}
```

I am getting this error `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`
is there any solution ?

Comment: you can use Apache HttpClient  for example

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work for me" means and provide what evidence you have to support it.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: [consuming api in java 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51792422/10832295)

Comment: Please Provide an error message or a clear explination on whats not working exactly

Comment: @Lalaluka you can check the question

Comment: @possum you can check the question

Comment: https://www.tutorialworks.com/java-trust-ssl/